# Email is going to own domain only

Tags: magento2, email

I am using transport builder to send mail in custom module.The emails are going successfully to all emails as per WHM, but unable to receive to any other domain. Able to receive the emails to own domain.

Comment: Sometimes your IP address may become blacklisted, if you lost your reputation by sending wrong e-mails. After you got a new IP address from your provider, it’s recommended not to use this address for at least a month. The reason behind this is that your new IP address might already be used by someone else before. This 1 month delay lets the IP address get cleared and became ‘white’.

Comment: @AdityaShah This is dev environment. Other emails (like order, invoice, shipment) are working fine. Its a new module. So no blacklisting or spam issue.

Comment: Okay, and checked Mail Sending Settings ?

Comment: What settings? Tried setting return emails yes, specific also.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the issue. In case someone have similar scenario. Someone played with dns setting and webmail.domain.com was not configured. Once configured it starts working.